Question about the proof of distribution of $\Omega(n)-\omega(n)$
On page 68 of the book Multiplicative Number Theory by Montgomery and Vaughan, in the last step of the proof of Theorem 1.16, we have the following:

Here we want to show that $d_k$ above is the $k$-th coefficients of the following series

How to see that multiplying $d_k$ by $z^k$ and summing over gives the desired series?

Please, avoid the use of images. Use MathJax to type the math in your questions.

As a courtesy to other site users, please replace the images with typeset versions of their content. Images diminish the searchability of the site, present barriers to those who use screen readers, etc.

The short answer is: sums of multiplicative functions have Euler products!
To start,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} d_mz^{m}&=\frac{6}{\pi^2} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} z^m \sum_{\substack{f\in\mathcal F \\ \Omega(f)-\omega(f)=m}} \frac1{f} \prod_{p\mid f} \biggl(1+\frac{1}{p} \biggr)^{-1} = \frac{6}{\pi^2} \sum_{f\in\mathcal F} \frac{z^{\Omega(f)-\omega(f)}}{f} \prod_{p\mid f} \biggl(1+\frac{1}{p} \biggr)^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Since ${\Omega(f)-\omega(f)}$ is additive, $z^{\Omega(f)-\omega(f)}$ is multiplicative. (Moreover, the implicit indicator function of the powerful numbers is also a multiplicative function.) Since
${z^{\Omega(f)-\omega(f)}}/{f} = \prod_{p^j\| f} {z^{\Omega(p^j)-\omega(p^j)}}/{p^j} = \prod_{p^j\| f} {z^{j-1}}/{p^j}$,
the sum on the right-hand side equals its Euler product
\begin{align*}
\frac{6}{\pi^2} \sum_{f\in\mathcal F} \frac{z^{\Omega(f)-\omega(f)}}{f} \prod_{p\mid f} \biggl(1+\frac{1}{p} \biggr)^{-1} &= \prod_{p} \biggl(1+\biggl(1+\frac{1}{p} \biggr)^{-1} \sum_{j= 2}^{\infty} \frac{z^{j-1}}{p^{j}} \biggr).
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} d_mz^{m} = \frac{6}{\pi^2} \prod_{p} \biggl(1+\biggl(1+\frac{1}{p} \biggr)^{-1} \sum_{j= 2}^{\infty} \frac{z^{j-1}}{p^{j}} \biggr) = \prod_{p} \biggl(1-\frac{1}{p^2} \biggr)\biggl(1+\biggl(1+\frac{1}{p} \biggr)^{-1} \frac{z/p^2}{1-z/p} \biggr),
$$
and the last step is simply the enjoyable algebra of simplifying the factor.
